# How to provide access to new user to "Custom Query" data source in Data Studio?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, looker-studio

I use data studio for reporting by connecting to BigQuery as a data source via 'Custom Query'.But the issue is I am the only one who can edit these data sources/queries.
I have contacted google support and they told only owner can edit/access the data source.

According, to below link the only owner can edit/access the data source :

https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7083608?hl=en

So, Could you please suggest on below if you also have faced a similar issue  :

1. How to provide 'Edit' access to use other than owner for editing the 'Custom Query'?
2. If it is not possible what can be the alternative or best practice so that we both can see and edit 'Custom  Query'.

Because it is strange what will happen if I will leave the company.if you faced the same issue what you did?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: sure.if that is the policy it can be closed.This is the product limitation I am struggling with currently.I have posted it on your suggested platform.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, the only solution I was able to come up with so far was to create a shared general Data Studio account and assign the ownership to that account (and share the credentials in our team), were you able to come up with any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can [share the Data Source](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6287179?hl=en) with relevant users with Edit access. That way they can also edit the Query.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I had tried that.As per current data studio limitation the only owner can edit the SQL Queries.I received the reply from google support today.According to them we can transfer the ownership to another account/Owner in your organisation It can be done by going to the sharing settings for both the report and data source, then select the person you want to transfer the report and data source to.

Answer (score 0):

As of the [February 11th 2021](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/10331528?hl=en) release, the way this works has now changed.

Data sources created while editing a report will be considered 'embedded' and the source will be fully editable (including the source connection, for example a custom query) by all editors of the report.

Data sources created from the main DataStudio menu will be considered 'reusable' and will have a specific owner (the person who created the source, or anyone they transferred ownership to). Reusable sources can then be used in multiple different reports.